# Carrying $id variable over in another file

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I recently found this tutorial http://www.infotuts.com/create-ajax-based-search-system-php-jquery/ and have noticed that all the results are displayed in search.php while search.php is called through ajax and displayed in index.php. Whenever I tried to integrate it into my website, my index.php contains a variable of $id which is shown in this url: (index.php?id=1) My problem is, I can't seem to get it to know what my $id is. I am unable to change the query in search.php to what I like as a result of this.

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from userdetail where name like '{$term}%'", $connection);
```

Here is the original query above me, however I want to have it dependent on the id of the page, so... :

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from userdetail where id = '$id' AND name like '{$term}%'", $connection);
```

The only problem is, that search.php has no idea what my $id variable is, even when I load it from index.php it does not work. Can anyone help?

The full code can be seen in the tutorial, but I can show you guys here. 
Search.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '12345');
$db = mysql_select_db('userdata', $connection);
$term = strip_tags(substr($_POST['searchit'],0, 100));
$term = mysql_escape_string($term); // Attack Prevention
if($term=="")
echo "Enter Something to search";
else{
$query = mysql_query("select * from userdetail where id = '$id' AND name like '{$term}%'", $connection);
$string = '';

if (mysql_num_rows($query)){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$string .= "<b>".$row['name']."</b> - ";
$string .= $row['email']."</a>";
$string .= "<br/>\n";
}

}else{
$string = "No matches found!";
}

echo $string;
}
?>
```

Here is index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax Based Search- InfoTuts</title>
<?php
$id = ((int)$_GET["id"]);
 ?>
<style type="text/css" >
#main {
padding: 10px;
margin: 100px;
margin-left: 300px;
color: Green;
border: 1px dotted;
width: 520px;
}
#display_results {
color: red;
background: #CCCCFF;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript "src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#search_results").slideUp();
$("#button_find").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
search_ajax_way();
});
$("#search_query").keyup(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
search_ajax_way();
});

});

function search_ajax_way(){
$("#search_results").show();
var search_this=$("#search_query").val();
$.post("search.php", {searchit : search_this}, function(data){
$("#display_results").html(data);

})
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<h1>Ajax Based Search System- InfoTuts</h1>
<form id="searchform" method="post">

<label>Enter</label>
<input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" placeholder="What You Are Looking For?" size="50"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="button_find" />

</form>
<div id="display_results"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide some more information..little bit unclear

Comment: Can you post your ajax code and php file?

Comment: I included it, but it is what I got off the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

In search.php file add the following code to accept the id from index.php file

```
<code>
    $term = mysql_escape_string($term); // Attack Prevention
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if(!empty($id)) {
        $query = mysql_query("select * from userdetail where id = '$id' AND name like '{$term}%'", $connection);
    } else {
       $query = mysql_query("select * from userdetail where name like '{$term}%'", $connection);
    }
    if($term=="")
        echo "Enter Something to search";
</code>
```

In the index.php file send the $id variable value along with the ajax request.

```
<code>
    function search_ajax_way(){
        $("#search_results").show();
        var search_this=$("#search_query").val();
        var id_val=$("#id").val();
        $.post("search.php", {searchit : search_this, id : id_val},   function(data){ $("#display_results").html(data);}
</code>
```

In the html add a input hidden field for id

```
<code>
    <form id="searchform" method="post">
        <label>Enter</label>
        <input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" placeholder="What You Are Looking For?" size="50"/>
        <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $id; ?>' id='id'/>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="button_find" />
    </form>
</code>
```

Comment: Unreal, it worked. I understand the php part but I don't really understand what you did in the ajax part that made it carry the id over.

Answer (score 0):

in

Please mention **action='search.php'** in form then it will redirect to search.php...and there you will get $id...

Comment: you want to submit form on index.php and want to get submitted values from there to search.php is it?

Comment: Yes but this is using AJAX. It's an automatic process and when I put action='search.php' in the form, that has no effect on it. No matter how many times I reference $id in search.php, it will not work.

Comment: Where you are passing $id which is getting from index.php?id=1...that will need to pass to your ajax file..

Comment: If you are posting your form details thr ajax then remove type="submit"...keep type="button"...